# Broken pin on the back of GPU normal?

Tags: computer-building

I recently bought an RX 570 4GB (Armor) from Amazon and while checking out the back of it, I noticed there was a missing pin. Is this normal? Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfBcZ.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is normal. (And it isn't broken.)

That 3-PIN IC (78M05G) is a voltage regulator.

The middle pin, that appears unconnected, is the ground connection.
In many versions of the 7805 IC (there are several formfactors available) the entire back (bottom in this picture) of the thing acts as ground-pin as well. So you don't need to connect this middle pin when you are using the backing-plate in stead.

In this particular version of the IC they even made the middle pin too short to touch the PCB so the only option is to use the backing-plate.

As you can see the PCB actually includes the solder-pad for the middle PIN anyway. This is also not unusual as that gives the manufacturer the opportunity to use either version of the IC, depending on cost/availability of the ICs. Redesiging a PCB (and adjusting your SMD soldering robot) for a simple IC swap is quite expensive, so if you can make it so that either version of the IC can be used on the same PCB, that is a good thing.

Comment: Darn, you really know your tech, Tonny. I was about to send it back if it was a missing pin. Thanks a mill for your help and information. 

Comment: @Tony I've been doing IT in manufacturing environments for over 25 years. Including PCB manufacturing. It keeps amazing me how much bits of random knowledge you pick up over time.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for doing what you love.